# Worklight 6.1 - App Center Installer app not displaying iOS app on device

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I am using Worklight 6.1 and have built the App Center client (installer) application, and deployed it to my device. The app I want to download through it is not appearing in the list - only the catalog app is available. However, if I go to the Application Center management console I can do see the app there. If the App is marked as an installer it can then also be downloaded to the device directly but not through the App Center client application.

I have noted that the app does not contain a device family tag or a minimal iOS version on the  application properties page however these are set correctly to iphone, ipad and iOS 7 in the application description for the iOS project in xcode

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If your iOS device is an ipad (not an iphone), the effect that you see might be the following problem:

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1PI09315

The problem is solved in the latest ifix of Worklight 6.1.

Without the ifix, it is also possible to solve the problem locally, but caution: this local fix will degrade performances of the catalog view scrolling a little bit while using the official ifix does not degrade any performance. The local fix is:

- Open the IBMAppCenter worklight project from
  `<INSTALL_DIR>`/ApplicationCenter/installer/IBMAppCenter on
  Worklight studio.
- Edit the following file:
  IBMAppCenter/apps/AppCenter/common/js/appcenter/widgets/EdgeToE
  dgeStoreList.js
- Replace:

  return declare("appcenter.widgets.EdgeToEdgeStoreList",
  [EdgeToEdgeStoreList, LongListMixin], {

  by:

  return declare("appcenter.widgets.EdgeToEdgeStoreList",
  EdgeToEdgeStoreList, {